# error C2275: illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: visual-c++, struct, c89

Error is thrown at second line:

```
HRESULT Direct3DDevice9Wrapper::GetLight(DWORD Index, D3DLIGHT9 *)
{
     return Direct3DDevice9->GetLight(Index, D3DLIGHT9);
}
```

D3DLIGHT9 deffinition:

```
typedef struct _D3DLIGHT9 
{
     D3DLIGHTTYPE    Type;            /* Type of light source */
     D3DCOLORVALUE   Diffuse;         /* Diffuse color of light */
     D3DCOLORVALUE   Specular;        /* Specular color of light */
     D3DCOLORVALUE   Ambient;         /* Ambient color of light */
     D3DVECTOR       Position;         /* Position in world space */
     D3DVECTOR       Direction;        /* Direction in world space */
     float           Range;            /* Cutoff range */
     float           Falloff;          /* Falloff */
     float           Attenuation0;     /* Constant attenuation */
     float           Attenuation1;     /* Linear attenuation */
     float           Attenuation2;     /* Quadratic attenuation */
     float           Theta;            /* Inner angle of spotlight cone */
     float           Phi;              /* Outer angle of spotlight cone */
} D3DLIGHT9;
```

I'm working in VC++, Visual Studio 2012. There were similar posts about variable declaration problem for c89, but I can't get this code working.

Comment: `Direct3DDevice9` is a type. You are using it as if it were a variable. Ditto for `D3DLIGHT9`. You seem to know enough to use `DWORD Index` correctly - you wrote `GetLight(Index)`, not `GetLight(DWORD)`. So why are you confused about `D3DLIGHT9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't define a variable name for the `D3DLIGHT9` pointer in your function declaration. You just need to do this:

```
HRESULT Direct3DDevice9Wrapper::GetLight(DWORD Index, D3DLIGHT9 *pLight)
{
     return Direct3DDevice9->GetLight(Index, pLight);
}
```